# asymptotic of $x^{x^x} = n$

Tags: asymptotics, exponentiation

How find the asymptotic behavior for $x(n)$ 
if $x^{x^x} = n$?

I supposed that $x = O(\log\log{n})$
and took logarithm two times.

So I get
$x = O(\frac{\log\log{n}}{\log\log\log{n}})$

Is it right?
How to improve this estimate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's write

$$
\begin{align}
&\log\log n = L_2(n), \\
&\log\log\log n = L_3(n), \\
&\log\log\log\log n = L_4(n).
\end{align}
$$

Then from $x^{x^x} = n$ we get

$$
x\log x + L_2(x) = L_2(n), \tag{1}
$$

and so, since $x \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, we have

$$
x\log x \sim L_2(n) \tag{2}
$$

as $n \to \infty$.  Taking logs of this yields

$$
\log x + L_2(x) \sim L_3(n),
$$

from which it follows that

$$
\log x \sim L_3(n). \tag{3}
$$

By dividing $(2)$ by $(3)$ we then find that

$$
x \sim \frac{L_2(n)}{L_3(n)}, \tag{4}
$$

agreeing with your estimate.  To get the next term we iterate.

Taking logs of $(1)$ and rearranging yields

$$
\log x = L_3(n) - L_2(x) - \log\left(1 + \frac{L_2(x)}{x\log x}\right). \tag{5}
$$

From $(3)$ we know that

$$
L_2(x) = L_4(n) + o(L_4(n)),
$$

so we can rewrite $(5)$ as

$$
\log x = L_3(n) - L_4(n) + o(L_4(n)).
$$

Substituting these into $(1)$ yields

$$
x\Bigl(L_3(n) - L_4(n) + o(L_4(n))\Bigr) = L_2(n) - L_4(n) + o(L_4(n)). \tag{6}
$$

Now

$$
\Bigl(L_3(n) - L_4(n) + o(L_4(n))\Bigr)^{-1} = L_3(n)^{-1} + \frac{L_4(n)}{L_3(n)^2} + o\left(\frac{L_4(n)}{L_3(n)^2}\right),
$$

so we can conclude from $(6)$ that

$$
x = \frac{L_2(n)}{L_3(n)} + \frac{L_2(n) L_4(n)}{L_3(n)^2} + o\left(\frac{L_2(n) L_4(n)}{L_3(n)^2}\right)
$$

as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Other examples of this method can be found in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/540591/5531) and [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/550195/5531).

Comment: I think the final term in (5) should be $-\log(1+L_2(x)/(x\log x))$

Comment: Whoops, thanks for spotting that @Michael.

Comment: [Helpful graph. Top one is $x=y^{y^y}$; bottom one is your estimate.](http://i.imgur.com/pq8YDOa.png) (These grow _really_ slowly... note that the y-axis goes from $-4$ to $4$, while the x-axis goes from around $-600,000$ to $600,000$.)