# If $x^x=n$, how does $x$ grow asymptotically?

Tags: asymptotics, exponentiation

If $x^x=n$, how does $x$ grow asymptotically in terms of $n$?

We know that it grows slower than $\log n$, because $\log n^{\log n}>e^{\log n}=n$. But it grows faster than $\log \log n$, because $\log\log n^{\log\log n}<n$.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1055588/asymptotic-of-xxx-n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple manipulations show that
$$x=\frac {\log n}{W(\log n)} \sim \frac {\log n}{\log\log n} $$
where W is Lambert W function.

**Edit:**
$x\log x=\log n\Rightarrow \log x = W(\log n)\Rightarrow x=e^{W(\log n)}=\frac {\log n}{W(\log n)}\sim\frac {\log n}{\log\log n-\log\log\log n}$.

Comment: Could you please show the manipulations, and why $W(\log n)\sim \log\log n$? Also, I think you meant $\log n$ instead of $\log x$.

Comment: $x\log x=\log n\Rightarrow \log x = W(\log n)\Rightarrow x=e^{W(\log n)}=\frac {\log n}{W(\log n)}$. Also $W(x)\sim \log x$