# Does the Lambert W function tend to infinity?

Tags: lambert-w

Does $W(x)\to\infty$ as the real number $x\to+\infty$?

I find the equation (4.19) in paper https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1993/03/W.pdf. It shows $$W(x)=\log x-\log\log x+\cdots$$.

Assuming $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$, $x\to+\infty$, is the following equation $$\frac{1}{1+W(x)}\to0$$ OK? Or it convergesto  a certain value?

Comment: In fact $W(x) > \log x - \log\log x$ for $x > e$.  See, e.g., [this answer of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/463108/5531).

Answer (score 2):

$W(\infty)=x\iff x\,e^x=\infty$ . Obviously, if *x* were finite, then so were $\infty$, which is absurd.

Comment: I like that "absurd" is a mathematically correct thing to say.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it goes to infinity. If you have mathematica (or Wolfram Alpha), the Lambert function is available as ProductLog[]