# Solving for limit of integration

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int^0_{z_a} e^{\frac{-z^2}{2}} \, dz = 0.48 $$

How would I solve for the value of $z_a$ using a calculator?

Comment: How sophisticated of a calculator are we talking about?

Comment: A problem like this will yield a decimal approximation for $z_a$ most likely, so you will need to use a scientific (or higher grade) calculator.

Comment: I'm using casio 991 es plus.

Comment: @edison: Would you consider using tables that are online?

Comment: Do you know the $erf$ function ? Please answer.

Comment: @user99680: Yes, but I want to know how to solve this using a calculator.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: No. Does the calculator 991 es plus have that function?

Comment: One approach would be to start with an initial guess of $z_a \approx -0.48 \sqrt{\pi}$ and use Newton's method.

Comment: @AntonioVargas. I suppose that you admit that this Casio 991 has the $erf$ function available. What I am not sure looking at the documentation. Cheers :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, right, the integral would have to be calculated at each step too.  I assumed that it could be programmed to evaluate it to some precision using the trapezoid rule, but if not then that would be a problem.

Comment: You may need to use [Newton's method](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609972/newtons-method-numerical-analysis/609989#609989).

Answer (score 1):

Define

$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_z^0 e^{-t^2/2}\,dt.
$$

Here's a plot of $f(z)$:

[image]

There are two notable features of this plot:

- When $z$ is close to zero, $f(z)$ is very close to $-\sqrt{2\pi} z$. Indeed, by calculating the derivatives using the fundamental theorem of calculus we can show that $$\begin{align} f(z) &= f(0) + f'(0)z + \frac{f''(0)}{2}z^2 + O(z^3) \\&= -\sqrt{2\pi}z + O(z^3) \end{align}$$ as $z \to 0$.
- When $z$ is away from zero, $f(z)$ is very close to $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-t^2/2}\,dt = \frac{1}{2}.$$

You're interested in solving the equation

$$
f(z) = 0.48,
$$

and since $0.48$ is very close to $1/2$ we would expect that $z$ falls into the second category.  Let's calculate an initial guess $z_0$ for $z$.

---

Splitting the integral then integrating by parts we get

$$
\begin{align}
f(z) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-t^2/2}\,dt - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^z e^{-t^2/2}\,dt \\
&= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^z e^{-t^2/2}\,dt \\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^z t^{-1} d\left(e^{-t^2/2}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\left. t^{-1} e^{-t^2/2} \right|_{t=-\infty}^{t=z} + \int_{-\infty}^{z} t^{-2} e^{-t^2/2}\,dt\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} z^{-1} e^{-z^2/2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{z} t^{-2} e^{-t^2/2}\,dt.
\end{align}
$$

This new integral with its factor of $t^{-2}$ in the integrand is surely much smaller than the original when $z$ is large and negative, so our first approximation to $f(z)$ in this case would be

$$
f(z) \approx \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} z^{-1} e^{-z^2/2}.
$$

Here's a plot of $f(z)$ in blue versus this approximation in red:

[image]

So, if we wanted to solve an equation like

$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{2}-\epsilon
$$

(like we do, with $\epsilon = 0.02$), then we could get an approximate solution by instead solving

$$
\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} z^{-1} e^{-z^2/2} = \frac{1}{2}-\epsilon,
$$

which is the same as

$$
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \epsilon} = z e^{z^2/2}.
$$

Squaring this yields

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi \epsilon^2} = z^2 e^{z^2},
$$

which can be solved using the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) as

$$
z^2 = W(1/(2\pi \epsilon^2)).
$$

Finally, taking the negative square root (remember we want $z$ to be negative) yields

$$
z = -\sqrt{W(1/(2\pi \epsilon^2))}.
$$

For large $x$ it's known that $W(x) \approx \log x - \log\log x$ (for a proof see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/463108/5531)), so for small $\epsilon$ we have

$$
z \approx -\sqrt{\log \frac{1}{2\pi \epsilon^2} - \log\log \frac{1}{2\pi \epsilon^2}}.
$$

Thus our initial approximation $z_0$ for the solution to the equation

$$
f(z) = 0.48 = \frac{1}{2} - 0.02 = \frac{1}{2} - \epsilon
$$

is

$$
z_0 = -\sqrt{\log \frac{1}{2\pi \epsilon^2} - \log\log \frac{1}{2\pi \epsilon^2}}{\Bigg |}_{\epsilon = 0.02} \doteq -2.04859.
$$

---

Now, using this initial guess $z_0 = -2.04859$, we can obtain a more precise value for the root of

$$
f(z) = 0.48
$$

by using Newton's method.  Let's define $g(z) := f(z) - 0.48$, so that the equation we want to solve is

$$
g(z) = 0.
$$

Using the fundamental theorem of calculus we can calculate

$$
g'(z) = - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-z^2/2},
$$

so the iteration for Newton's method,

$$
z_{n+1} = z_n - \frac{g(z_n)}{g'(z_n)},
$$

is

$$
z_{n+1} = z_n + e^{z_n^2/2} \left(\int_{z_n}^0 e^{-t^2/2}\,dt - 0.48\sqrt{2\pi}\right).
$$

We then iterate this recurrence using the starting value $z_0 = -2.04859$ to obtain better approximations for the root.  Mathematica produces the iterates

$$
\begin{align}
z_1 &= -2.05372, \\
z_2 &= -2.05375, \\
z_3 &= -2.05375,
\end{align}
$$

so it looks like the root is $z \doteq -2.05375$ to six significant figures.  Indeed, the root is approximately

$$
z \doteq -2.05374\ 89106\ 31823\ 05294.
$$

The Casio fx-991EX PLUS has a button for numerical integration so this iteration process should be doable on your hand calculator.