# Solving $W$ function

Tags: calculus, lambert-w

What is the general form of Lambert $W$-function to calculate any $x$ in $\mathbb R$?

I had problems solving for $x, x^2-e^x=0$.
I reached $x=-2W(\frac12)$.

What does $W(\frac12)$ equal to?

Comment: See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Special_values).

Comment: There are some calculators for lambert functions. Just google and you'll find what you want.

Comment: An approximation is $ln(x) - ln(ln(x))$, which I got from this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463055/approximation-to-the-lambert-w-function

Answer (score 7):

There is no "general form of the Lambert W-function". All you have is the definition, tables, power series, other numerical methods. It's like the trigonometric functions - no algebraic "formula".

From wikipedia:

> The Lambert W relation cannot be expressed in terms of elementary
>   functions.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Nowadays the trig functions are so common that you don't tend to think of them as special in that way. 
The Lambert W-function seems to appear more and more often on this site. Perhaps some day people will view it as just another special function.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:

As Ethan Bolker said, in general the only way to do it is using a computer and approximation methods. When a computer evaluates $W(z)$, it generally uses an approximation method.

Longer answer:

One such approximation method is as follows. It's an iterative method, which means you pick a starting number as a guess, plug it into the formula, and a better guess comes out. Repeat until you get the desired precision.

> Source: 1996: R.M. Corless, G.H. Gonnet, D.E.G Hare, D.J. Jeffrey and
>   D.E.  Knuth: On the Lambert W Function (Vol. 5: 329 – 359)

Quoted verbatim, except for changed formatting:

> We return to the specific problem at hand that of computing a value
>   of $W_k(z)$ for arbitrary integer $k$ and complex $z$ .
>
> Taking full advantage of the features of iterative rootfinders
>   outlined above we compared the efficiency of three methods, namely,
>
> `(1)` Newton's method
>
> `(2)` Halley's method
>
> `(3)` the fourth order method described in `[30]` (as published this last method evaluates only the principal branch of $W$ at
>   positive real arguments but it easily extends to all branches and to
>   all complex arguments)
>
> ...  The results showed quite consistently that method `(2)` is
>   the optimal method ...
>
> For the $W$ function, Halley's method takes the form:
>
> $$w_{j+1} = w_j - \frac{w_j e^{w_j}-z}{e^{w_j}(w_j+1)-\frac{(w_j+2)w_je^{w_j}-z}{2w_j + 2}}$$

You can find more information about Newton's Method and Halley's method on Wikipedia. Let me know if you're confused about the notation, what $k$ means, or what a "branch" is.

If there's more than one solution to $x = We^W$, then you have to pick one in order for $W$ to be a function. For real numbers, $x=We^W$ has a unique solution $W$ for $x>0$, has two solutions for $-\frac 1 e \le x \le 0$ and no solution for $x < -\frac 1 e$. So we "cut off the branch" that gives us the second solution for $-\frac 1 e \le x \le 0$, and the remaining function is called the "principal branch".

Comment: I want to know what a branch is ?

Comment: @Xygo added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

A longish comment:

Even without actually knowing what the Lambert function is, you can get a reasonably good answer by knowing that $x$ is reasonably small (you know this since $x^2-e^x$ is monotonic, and checking the values at say $x=-1,0$).

If you expand $e^x$, and keep only up to the quadratic term, you have:
$$x^2=1+x+x^2/2$$
Which gives:
$$x= 1-\sqrt{1+2}\approx 0.73$$
Which is pretty close. You can then use Newton's method to refine if needed.