# how to use newton's method to approximate a function

Tags: approximation, newton-raphson

i was wondering how [this user](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/463223) managed to use newton's method to approximate an actual function (that being the lambert w function) rather than its roots.

i cannot seem to follow his logic, and through my research i have only come across examples of people using newtons method to approximate the roots of a function, not the function itself.

how could i use what he has done to approximate, say, ln(x) in a similar manner?

Comment: This works if the Newton sequence converges pointwise to the solution. In this case , we can actually iterate the complete function and get after some iterations a more or less good approximation.

Comment: @Peter forgive me, but could you explain this in layman's terms? or give another example of a function with this property? i apologize for my inexperience with the subject